# Declare scope value in span tag on angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pie-chart

I've created the pie chart and want to pass the value dynamically in pie chart.When i pass the value in span tag with use of ng-bind.It is not working and page is not loading.
     When pass the value it hangs the page.

**HTML page**

```
<div ng-controller="piechart">
<div class="pieID pie">
</div>
<ul class="pieID legend">
  <li>
    <em>marks1</em>
    <span ng-bind="marks1"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <em>marks2</em>
    <span ng-bind="marks2"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <em>marks3</em>
    <span ng-bind="marks3"></span>
  </li>      
</ul>
</div>
```

**Controller.js**

```
myAppControllers.controller('piechart',['$scope', '$http', 
function($scope,$http) {
 function sliceSize(dataNum, dataTotal) {
 return (dataNum / dataTotal) * 360;
 }
 function addSlice(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color) {
   $(pieElement).append("<div class='slice "+sliceID+"'><span></span>   </div>");
  var offset = offset - 1;
  var sizeRotation = -179 + sliceSize;
  $("."+sliceID).css({
  "transform": "rotate("+offset+"deg) translate3d(0,0,0)"
  });
  $("."+sliceID+" span").css({
  "transform"       : "rotate("+sizeRotation+"deg) translate3d(0,0,0)",
  "background-color": color
 });
  }
  function iterateSlices(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, dataCount, sliceCount, color) {
  var sliceID = "s"+dataCount+"-"+sliceCount;
  var maxSize = 179;
  if(sliceSize<=maxSize) {
  addSlice(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color);
   } else {
   addSlice(maxSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color);
   iterateSlices(sliceSize-maxSize, pieElement, offset+maxSize, dataCount, sliceCount+1, color);
   }
   }
   function createPie(dataElement, pieElement) {
    var listData = [];
    $(dataElement+" span").each(function() {
listData.push(Number($(this).html()));
  });
  var listTotal = 0;
 for(var i=0; i<listData.length; i++) {
listTotal += listData[i];
 }
 var offset = 0;
 var color = [
 "cornflowerblue", 
 "olivedrab", 
 "orange", 
 "tomato", 
 "crimson", 
 "purple", 
 "turquoise", 
 "forestgreen", 
 "navy", 
 "gray"
 ];
 for(var i=0; i<listData.length; i++) {
 var size = sliceSize(listData[i], listTotal);
 iterateSlices(size, pieElement, offset, i, 0, color[i]);
 $(dataElement+" li:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").css("border-color", color[i]);
 offset += size;
 }
 }
 createPie(".pieID.legend", ".pieID.pie");

 $scope.marks1=50;
 $scope.marks2=80;
 $scope.marks3=55;   
 }]);
```

Comment: could you please provide a fiddle or complete source code

Comment: Works for me:  http://plnkr.co/edit/QUdnJsBJ0HZwAXz5Uy5h?p=preview Perhaps you should check your console for errors.  Check to make sure your angular is loaded.  Make sure all your script files are included.

Comment: In pie chart it is not working ,sometime the page is not loading

Comment: There is nowehere where we can see the code for your pichart here.

Comment: Call the createPie wrapped with $timeout. It will wait for the complete angular cycle before your DOM update: $timeout(function() { createPie(...); })